# add to the timeline widget a filter button in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a container on the program page. In this container, I display the history of events in the timeline widget. Everything is displayed as needed. But I want to add a filter button. When I click this button, I want the filter to work and select the desired events. But I don't understand how to properly add a button to a container.
My scrin (timeline widget) :

[image]

Code container :

```html
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7, 0, 7, 7),
                    child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(width: 1.5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                height: 45,
                                child: Text("история событий", style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Scrollbar(
                                    child: new ListView(
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      children: [

                                        new Container(
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                            child: FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(

                                              theme: TimelineThemeData(
                                                nodePosition: 0.23,
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                                indicatorTheme: IndicatorThemeData(
                                                  position: 2,
                                                  size: 20.0,
                                                ),
                                                connectorTheme: ConnectorThemeData(
                                                  thickness: 2.5,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              builder: TimelineTileBuilder
                                                  .connectedFromStyle(
                                                contentsAlign: ContentsAlign
                                                    .basic,
                                                oppositeContentsBuilder: (
                                                    context, index) =>
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                          .all(8.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                          _userDetails[index]
                                                              .date),
                                                    ),
                                                contentsBuilder: (context,
                                                    index) =>
                                                    Card(
                                                      child: Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                            .all(8.0),
                                                        child: Text(
                                                            _userDetails[index]
                                                                .event),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                connectorStyleBuilder: (context,
                                                    index) =>
                                                ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
                                                indicatorStyleBuilder: (context,
                                                    index) =>
                                                IndicatorStyle.dot,
                                                itemCount: _userDetails.length,
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        ),

                                      ],
                                    ))),
                          ],
                        ))))
```

here I want to add a filter button (blue frame):
[image]

New scrin:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
                     Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            height: 45,
                            child: Text("история событий", style:                                                                                                 
                              TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25.0, color: 
                                Colors.blueGrey)),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                        Expanded( /// <-- add from
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: 
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children:[
                              SizedBox(),
                              Container(
                                width: 30, 
                                height: 30,                                     
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.blue)),])), <--to
                         Expanded....
```

Comment: thanks, but there was a problem in the line "alignment: Alignment.spaceBetween," (The getter 'spaceBetween' isn't defined for the type 'Alignment'.) (Documentation) Try importing the library that defines 'spaceBetween', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'spaceBetween'.)

Comment: `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, i wrote by hands into that editor, here no compile errors)

Comment: can I raise this button even higher? because it is too low and the whole history of events has fallen

Comment: I added an updated screen to my question

Comment: you can replace `Expanded` from my example code to `Container` with `width: double.infinity` and `height: 35` for example or use `Flexible` with `flex` param for all of your widgets in first `Column`